# How do I create a "Down For Maintenance" Page in AWS Amplify?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I have a React site which is hosted using AWS Amplify, and I want to make a "Down for Maintenance" page which will appear automatically when the site is being updated.

I can't see anything in the docs about how to do this, and I am very unfamiliar with AWS, so I've no idea where to start.  Can someone point me in the right direction (I don't even know whether I'm supposed to be using Amplify for this)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty new to the AWS environment myself too but here is how I did it.

- Create a "maintenance" branch
- Go to Amplify > Domain Management > Manage Subdomains
- Change the branch that your domain points to, from "master" to "maintenance" when needed.